# biblatex - volume and issue in words and with comma in front of them

Tags: biblatex

So the current product looks like this:

> Gillies, A. (1933), “Herder and the Preparation of Goethe’s Idea of World Literature”,
>   in: Publications of the English Goethe Society 9 (2), pp. 46–67.

Due to guidelines I must produce this though:

> Gillies, A. (1933), “Herder and the Preparation of Goethe’s Idea of World Literature”,
>   in: Publications of the English Goethe Society, vol. 9, iss. 2, pp. 46–67.

("Volume" and "issue" would be fine as well.)

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
a4paper
]
{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[
language=auto,
style=authoryear,
backend=bibtex,
hyperref=true,
isbn=false,
doi=false,
citereset=chapter,
maxcitenames=3,
dashed=false,
sorting=nyt,
natbib=true, %faking natbib-commands
firstinits=true,
terseinits=false
maxbibnames=99,
%autopunct=true,
uniquename=init
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space} 

\begin{filecontents*}{lit.bib}

@Article{gillies,
  hyphenation     = {british},
  author      = {Gillies, Alexander},
  title       = {Herder and the Preparation of Goethe's Idea of World Literature},
  journaltitle    = {Publications of the English Goethe Society},
  volume      = {9},
    issue = {2},
  date        = {1933},
  pages       = {46--67},
  annotation      = {An \texttt{article} entry with a \texttt{series} and a \texttt{volume} field.
            Note that format of the \texttt{series} field in the database file}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{lit.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\begin{itemize}
    \item For the case of multiple editors, these are just some words.\footcite[See][p. xi]{gillies}.
\end{itemize}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I notice that you want the ``number`` field to also print 'vol.', is that correct ?

Comment: Oh. Nice catch. No, I do not want that. I amended my MWE.

Comment: So you want to print the ``incollection`` article as is ? My answer below assumes the original objective

Comment: Actually, after a second thorough look into the guidelines, you highlighted an ambiguous item which seems to be technically wrong. So thanks for that as well, your comment about the `number` field printing *volume* or *vol.* is quite helpful. I am to try out the code you provided, I am sure it is going to work and I can choose either method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following achieves the customization that you wanted. It is a lot of code (but mostly repetition of default code) purely because I wanted to make it a bit more robust. It's not perfect ( I ran out of time and hacked a bit) but it should work.

**Note**: As the solutions stands the comma and space before the `number` field in `incollection` will only be present if the series field is immediately before (should always be the case, though)

**EDIT:** if the incollection ref should print as-is, you need to comment out the lines marked in the code below - that way the representation of `number` will be unchanged

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
a4paper
]
{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[
language=auto,
style=authoryear,
backend=bibtex,
hyperref=true,
isbn=false,
doi=false,
citereset=chapter,
maxcitenames=3,
dashed=false,
sorting=nyt,
natbib=true, %faking natbib-commands
firstinits=true,
terseinits=false
maxbibnames=99,
%autopunct=true,
uniquename=init
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space} 

\begin{filecontents*}{lit.bib}
@InCollection{brandt,
  options     = {useprefix=false},
  hyphenation     = {german},
  indexsorttitle  = {Nordischen Lander von der Mitte des 11. Jahrhunderts bis 1448},
  author      = {von Brandt, Ahasver and Hoffmann, Erich},
  editor      = {Ferdinand Seibt},
  indextitle      = {Nordischen L{\"a}nder von der Mitte des 11.~Jahrhunderts bis 1448, Die},
  title       = {Die nordischen L{\"a}nder von der Mitte des 11.~Jahrhunderts bis 1448},
  shorttitle      = {Die nordischen L{\"a}nder},
  booktitle   = {Europa im Hoch- und Sp{\"a}tmittelalter},
  series      = {Handbuch der europ{\"a}ischen Geschichte},
  number      = {2},
  publisher   = {Klett-Cotta},
  location    = {Stuttgart},
  date        = {1987},
  pages       = {884--917},
  annotation      = {An \texttt{incollection} entry with a \texttt{series} and a \texttt{number}.
            Note the format of the printed name and compare the \texttt{useprefix} option in
            the \texttt{options} field as well as \texttt{vangennep}. Also note the
            \texttt{indextitle, and \texttt{indexsorttitle} fields}}
}
@Article{gillies,
  hyphenation     = {british},
  author      = {Gillies, Alexander},
  title       = {Herder and the Preparation of Goethe's Idea of World Literature},
  journaltitle    = {Publications of the English Goethe Society},
  volume      = {9},
    issue = {2},
  date        = {1933},
  pages       = {46--67},
  annotation      = {An \texttt{article} entry with a \texttt{series} and a \texttt{volume} field.
            Note that format of the \texttt{series} field in the database file}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{lit.bib}

%taken from standard.bbx
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}% THIS LINE CHANGED to add comma
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

%taken from standard.bbx
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \printtext{%   REMOVED parenthesis here
    \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{date}}
      {\printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \usebibmacro{date}}}%
  \newunit}

%modified from english.lbx
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    issue  = {\lowercase{i}ss\adddot}, % avoid capitalization after dots.
}

%modified from biblatex.def
%starred version removes entry specific formatting
\DeclareFieldFormat*{volume}{\bibstring{volume}~#1\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{issue}{\bibstring{issue}~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1} %comment to leave number as before
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{series}{{#1}\addcomma\space} %comment to leave number as before


\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\begin{itemize}
    \item For the case of multiple editors, these are just some words.\footcite[See][p. xi]{gillies}.
    \item Something for the other thing.\footcite{brandt}
\end{itemize}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If you would like to have 'vol.' instead of 'no.' an easy fix for that is to replace

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    issue  = {\lowercase{i}ss\adddot}, % avoid capitalization after dots.
}
```

with

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    number = {\lowercase{v}ol\adddot}, % avoid capitalization after dots.
    issue  = {\lowercase{i}ss\adddot}, % avoid capitalization after dots.
}
```

Comment: I have a question: so I had [this](http://pastebin.com/gfu8EewT) in my biblatex-file. Now that I see *your* last paragraph with the some same fieldformat declarations, I am wondering if if can use both, except for your `journaltitle`. They way I see it, I think these are indeed different fields and there should be no consistency problem. Right?

Comment: Yes you should be able to use your field formats, removing my ``journaltitle`` one.