# Change the periodic style in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I have searched a bit without finding a solution. I want to change the biblatex style (citation and bibliography), regarding the "number" field in periodics and others.

I would like to change this :

> Zerrouk Yamina, « Gestion des sites et sols pollués et fiucie », JCP 
>   9 (28 fév. 2014), p. 47.

Into this :

> Zerrouk Yamina, « Gestion des sites et sols pollués et fiucie », JCP **,
>   n° 9** (28 fév. 2014), p. 47.

I already have bbx and cbx files, so I would like to add a potential change in those files. I didn't find anything in the documentation...  I use lualatex.

Thanks a lot for any help ! :)

Comment: What you ask for isn't terribly complicated (and I'm sure a bit of searching for `biblatex` and `volume` - the field you are looking to change is very probably the `volume`, not the `number` field - will give you an idea how to achieve this yourself), it would be quite unfortunate if someone were to give an answer that does not work on your set-up, because we cannot test a solution. So please provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) or at least tell us what `biblatex` style you use and if you have any other modifications for it.

Comment: Since there has not be a response with more specifics, I voted to close as duplicate of [biblatex - volume and issue in words and with comma in front of them](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114435/35864), as this seems to ask for pretty much the same thing.