# Customize biblatex authoryear bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to customize a the biblatex authoryear style.

In the footnote I only need to call for the Surname, Year and Page number. In the bibliography I need to repeat this short reference in bold and then give full reference.

Please see the picture attached (above are footnotes, below are full references in the bibliography).

Could anyone explain how to make this work?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{rosati13,
 author = {E. Rosati},
  year = {2013},
  title = {Originality in EU Copyright: Full Harmonization through Case Law},
  address   = {Cheltenham},
  publisher = {Edward Elgar},
}

@article{rosati14,
  author = {E. Rosati},
  year = {2014},
  title = {Copyright in the EU: in search of (in)flexibilities},
  journal = {Journal of Intellectual Property Law \& Practice},
  number = {7},
  pages   = {585-598},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite[8]{rosati13}

\cite[585]{rosati14}

\printbibliography

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}The references need to look like this:\\

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}\textbf{Rosati 2013}\\
E. Rosati, \textit{Originality in EU Copyright: Full Harmonization through Case Law}, Cheltenham: Edward Elgar 2014.\\

\textbf{Rosati 2014}\\
E. Rosati, `Copyright in the EU: in search of (in)flexibilities', \textit{Journal of Intellectual Property Law \& Practice} 2014, issue 7, p. 585-598.

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: We will only be able to help you properly once we know how exactly you build your bibliography, that is best shown in an MWE. [Adding an AuthorYear block at the beginning of bibliography entries](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11827/35864) and [Revisiting: “Adding an AuthorYear block at the beginning of bibliography entries”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303519/35864) should be able to give you some ideas.

Comment: @samcarter Does the MWE above help?

Comment: There is no picture attached...

Comment: @CarLaTeX Sorry, accidentally deleted the image when I added the code.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{rosati13,
        author = {E. Rosati},
        year = {2013},
        title = {Originality in EU Copyright: Full Harmonization through Case Law},
        address   = {Cheltenham},
        publisher = {Edward Elgar},
    }

    @article{rosati14,
        author = {E. Rosati},
        year = {2014},
        title = {Copyright in the EU: in search of (in)flexibilities},
        journal = {Journal of Intellectual Property Law \& Practice},
        number = {7},
        pages   = {585-598},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\baselineskip}

\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
    \textbf{\usebibmacro{cite}}\par%
    \printnames{author}
}


\begin{document}

    \cite[8]{rosati13}

    \cite[585]{rosati14}



    \printbibliography

    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}The references need to look like this:\\

    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}\textbf{Rosati 2013}\\
    E. Rosati, \textit{Originality in EU Copyright: Full Harmonization through Case Law}, Cheltenham: Edward Elgar 2014.\\

    \textbf{Rosati 2014}\\
    E. Rosati, `Copyright in the EU: in search of (in)flexibilities', \textit{Journal of Intellectual Property Law \& Practice} 2014, issue 7, p. 585-598.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Any way to include [1] include the year, [2] include the word 'issue', and [3] remove the 'In:' for journal articles (not for books)?

Comment: @Gustaaf [3] http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10682/suppress-in-biblatex

Comment: @Gustaaf [2] http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114435/biblatex-volume-and-issue-in-words-and-with-comma-in-front-of-them

Answer (score 2):

I would go with a variation of [lockstep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/510/lockstep)'s answer to [Adding an [AuthorYear] block at the beginning of bibliography entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11827/35864)

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family}

\newcounter{mymaxcitenames}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setcounter{mymaxcitenames}{\value{maxnames}}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \printtext[bold]{%
    \begingroup
    \defcounter{maxnames}{\value{mymaxcitenames}}%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
    \endgroup
    }%
  \newline
}
```

You will need to load `biblatex` with the options `style=authoryear,bibstyle=authortitle,dashed=false,sorting=nyt`, so that your bibliography has the author-title format with the year at the end and the right ordering

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,bibstyle=authortitle,dashed=false,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
```

The other details can be achieved with

```
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \iffieldundef{issue}
    {\usebibmacro{date}}
    {\printfield{issue}%
     \setunit*{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{date}}%
  \newunit}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{number = {issue}}
```

Where the `in:` code is from [Suppress “In:” biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864)

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,bibstyle=authortitle,dashed=false,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{rosati13,
 author = {E. Rosati},
  year = {2013},
  title = {Originality in EU Copyright: Full Harmonization through Case Law},
  address   = {Cheltenham},
  publisher = {Edward Elgar},
}

@article{rosati14,
  author = {E. Rosati},
  year = {2014},
  title = {Copyright in the EU: in search of (in)flexibilities},
  journal = {Journal of Intellectual Property Law \& Practice},
  number = {7},
  pages   = {585-598},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \iffieldundef{issue}
    {\usebibmacro{date}}
    {\printfield{issue}%
     \setunit*{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{date}}%
  \newunit}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{number = {issue}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family}

\newcounter{mymaxcitenames}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setcounter{mymaxcitenames}{\value{maxnames}}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \printtext[bold]{%
    \begingroup
    \defcounter{maxnames}{\value{mymaxcitenames}}%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
    \endgroup
    }%
  \newline
}

\begin{document}
\cite{rosati13,rosati14}

\printbibliography

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}The references need to look like this:\\

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}\textbf{Rosati 2013}\\
E. Rosati, \textit{Originality in EU Copyright: Full Harmonization through Case Law}, Cheltenham: Edward Elgar 2014.\\

\textbf{Rosati 2014}\\
E. Rosati, `Copyright in the EU: in search of (in)flexibilities', \textit{Journal of Intellectual Property Law \& Practice} 2014, issue 7, p. 585-598.
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]